# Where Can I access My Mautic campaign content (File path)

Tags: mautic

Im trying to extract all of my sms content and email content from a mautic install and put it into another install. What is the file path where these are stored?

Comment: Q: Have you asked on the Mautic community: https://www.mautic.org/community/?   I'm guessing that everything you're interested in is stored in the Mautic database.  SUGGESTION: simply make a backup.  For example: https://www.mautic.org/blog/developer/backup-mautic-database-in-dropbox/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested, the data will be stored in your database, and any files uploaded will be in the file system (most likely in /media/images if you didn't modify the location).